# How do I style GeoJSONs based on conditionals (greater than, less than, etc.)?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

**This problem is unlike the question suggested as a duplicate**

I am making a GMaps JS API-based app. When I send a GET request, I get a GeoJSON like this:

```
{
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
        {
            "geometry":{
                "type":"MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates":[/* Array of coordinates */]
            },
            "type":"Feature",
            "styleData":28630.87
        },
        {... More objects like above }
    ]
}
```

The code I have so far for trying to put GeoJSONs on my Map:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapWrapperElement, mapOptionsObject);
$.getJSON(getRequestURLToGetGeoJSON, function(data){
    var geoJSONFeatures = map.data.addGeoJson(data);
    map.data.setStyle(function(feature){
        console.log(feature);
        console.log(feature.getProperty('stylingData'));
    });
});
```

The first `console.log()` prints a circular object with coordinate info and other properties of `feature`. The second one prints `undefined` to the console.

How do I style each `feature` so that if its `"styleData"` is more than 0, it's one color, and if it's more than 1000 it's another?

Comment: How? Where in the GMaps API documentation does it state this? I would post this question to the Google Group, but the moderators there want anyone trying to learn this to post to Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: What does your existing code look like? What are the value ranges? What colors do they map to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting different fill colors for geoJSON objects in Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138463/setting-different-fill-colors-for-geojson-objects-in-google-maps-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640520/rendering-polygons-and-multipolygons-from-geojson-and-or-dynamically-in-differen

Comment: Yep, it's a dupe.